# Spring AOP no error but does not executes advice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am new to spring AOP, and tried below code by following [baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-annotation) article.

Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    @Around("@annotation(Debug)")
    public Object beforeDebug(ProceedingJoinPoint debugJoinpoint) {
        LOGGER.debug("----------------Debug message logged from {}", debugJoinpoint.getSignature().toString());
        System.out.println("IN HERE");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Object proceed = null;
        try {
            proceed = debugJoinpoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        System.out.println(debugJoinpoint.getSignature() + " executed in " + executionTime + "ms");
        return proceed;
    }
}
```

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
@Loggable(type = "debug")
public @interface Debug {
}
```

Demo class for testing:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Component
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        dumb();
    }

    @Debug
    public static void dumb() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Can someone please point out what am I doing wrong above? The advice just won't execute and I am not able to solve this after googling here and there, not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Its in the demo class, annotated the method with @Debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring AOP only works for non-static methods as shown in the Baeldung example and documented in the Spring manual.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Can you also answer another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667039/using-aspectj-project-as-a-jar-in-other-projects, I am very confused on it. I have read quite a few answers of yours, and If you are aware about it, then pls help.