# Using AspectJ project as a jar in other projects

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Being new to AspectJ and Spring AOP, I have a Spring AOP project with Aspects defined in it. Pointcut is defined on annotation `Loggable`. Whenever a method with `@Loggable` is executed the advices should get executed.

Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Loggable {

    String customMessage() default "";

    String[] properties() default {};
    
    String type();
}
```

Below is the Aspect class:
LoggingAspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Around("loggablePointcut(loggableAnnotation)")
    public Object beforeDebug(ProceedingJoinPoint joinpoint, Loggable loggableAnnotation) throws Throwable {
        final String logType = loggableAnnotation.type();

        LOGGER.log(Level.toLevel(logType), joinpoint.getSignature().toString() + " - " + loggableAnnotation.customMessage());
        System.out.println("in here");

        // Default Object that we can use to return to the consumer
        Object returnObject = null;

        try {
            returnObject = joinpoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw throwable;
        }

        return returnObject;
    }

    @Pointcut("@annotation(loggableAnnotation)")
    public void loggablePointcut(Loggable loggableAnnotation) {
    }
}
```

Now to make the app runnable and testing once locally:
Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Loggable(type = "info")
    public void testing() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        System.out.println("testing");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        Application app = (Application) ctx.getBean("application");
        app.testing();
        System.err.println("Executed from project A");
    }
}
```

Till here everything works fine. Now my actual requirement is to use these aspects in my other spring boot projects. I read [this article here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Introducing-AJDT/article.html), but couldn't seem to understand it.

I am confused with following questions:

Q1. How to export the AspectJ project as a jar in other projects? Do I right click and export it as jar and import the generated jar and everything will work? (I tried this but it didnt work)

Q2. Any other options I can use here?

### EDIT:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring_AOP</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Spring_AOP</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

These are the only files I have.

Comment: (1) The article you read is not about Spring AOP but about the Eclipse integration of AspectJ, the AspectJ Development Tools (AJDT). (2) Spring AOP is not the same as AspectJ. It uses other technology and is just proxy-based "AOP lite", while AspectJ is a full-featured AOP language, much more powerful than Spring AOP. So which of the two are you using? You are not providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. I see no Spring config here. Thus I cannot answer your question, please update it. (3) That article is not an AspectJ tutorial at all, it just describes AJDT.

Comment: @kriegaex Thank your for your response, But I don't have any spring config file in my project, everything is annotation based, only thing i missed out was my pom.xml which i just updated, please let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: So what? Show me your annotation-based configuration then. I never said it had to be XML.

Comment: It is shared already, the logging aspect.java file, I have only these many files in my project and it works completely fine. The problem comes when I try to import it another project.

Comment: Please post a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, either one multi-module project or two separate projects. I need to see exactly how you do it. I tried with your classes and with your POM, seperated aspect + annotation out to a second JAR and used it as a dependency in the Spring Boot application. No problems there, the aspect is picked up and does its job as expected. You might be making a mistake in Maven dependency handling.

Comment: So what's up, pal? No feedback? I still have my functioning two projects here, ready to be compared to yours and help you. I will be quite busy soon, so maybe you hurry up with the MCVE if you want help.

Comment: Hi Pal, sorry I didn't get a chance to update my status here, but it started working after I did maven clean and added "aspectj" project dependency to my pom.xml. the issue was my aop project wasn't on classpath. Thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: So you did have the time to steal other people's time by writing a question a month ago, but actually you do not care about the answers. Thank you very much.